# Parse Nested JSON of Firebase Database and set Data in RecyclerView

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-json

[image]

I am using `FirebaseDatabase` in my application. I need to set data in `RecyclerView`.The key `Om Namah Shivay` has two nested keys `Dinner` and `Lunch` under it.I need to set data in Recyclerview such that it will have two rows and contain Dinner and Lunch Data as separate entries in RecyclerView.
How to parse this nested JSON and set data ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.